# Find matching pattern and replace variable value in next line

Tags: linux, bash, yaml, github-actions

I am trying to replace the value of a variable "Tag" next to the searched pattern, like:

If name in images is "repo.url/app1"
Replace Tag: NEW_VALUE

Below is the yaml sample file where I need to replace the values.

```
namespace: dev

resources:
- file.yaml
- ../../..

images:
- name: repo.url/app1
  Tag: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
- name: repo.url/app2
  Tag: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So far I tried
`sed -i "/\-\ name\:\ repo.url\/app1/{n;n;s/\(Tag\).*/\1: $NEW_VALUE/}" file`
which doesn't do anything and doesn't throw any error. I am not sure, if there's a better way to handle such substitutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way with `sed` is just to match the line and then perform the substitution on the next (`\w` used to match all word-characters at the end of the line for replacement), e.g.

```bash
sed -E '/repo\.url\/app1$/{n;s/\w+$/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/}' file.yaml
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
sed -E '/repo\.url\/app1$/{n;s/\w+$/yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/}' file.yaml
namespace: dev

resources:
- file.yaml
- ../../..

images:
- name: repo.url/app1
  Tag: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
- name: repo.url/app2
  Tag: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Using `awk`**

Another way is to use `awk` and a flag to indicate replace in next line (`rep` below). Then use `sub()` to replace the `'x'`s with whatever you need, e.g.

```bash
awk '
  rep { sub(/\w+$/,"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"); rep = 0 } 
  $NF == "repo.url/app1" { rep=1 }
  1
' file.yaml
```

Where `1` is just shorthand for print current record.

**Example Use/Output**

```
awk 'rep { sub(/\w+$/,"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"); rep = 0 } $NF == "repo.url/app1" { rep=1 }1' file.yaml
namespace: dev

resources:
- file.yaml
- ../../..

images:
- name: repo.url/app1
  Tag: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
- name: repo.url/app2
  Tag: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Just redirect the output to a new file to save, e.g. `awk '{...}' file.yaml > newfile.yaml`.